# Running an *attached* screen session asynchronously

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I am trying to write a script which creates an interactive screen session in the background and retains control of the process so it can do other things (like split the screen the session when certain things occur, etc). So far I have tried 'screen&' but this breaks things horribly I suspect this has something to do with the way ncurses controls the terminal. I know it's possible to do thing with screens initialization process, but this is not what I am looking for (the script needs to be able to modify the session at potentially random intervals after initialization). Any advice/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a session without actually attaching to it.

```
screen -d -m
```

Then you can send commands as necessary to the detached session.

Comment: As I mentioned my goal is to have the user be able to interact with the session while I am interacting with it.